# How do I backup photos to iOS Google Photos without duplicating photos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-photos

My photos have synced to my Google account using the iOS `Google Photos` app.

Each photo is now taking twice the storage on my phone: the `iOS Photos` app **and** the `Google Photos` app.

Inside `Google Photos` there is an option to remove the uploaded photos from the `iOS Photos` app but I don't want that.

I want to remove the photos from `Google Photos` but I still want to be able to view the photos in the `Google Photos` app that were uploaded to my Google account.

Basically, I want to back up my photos to `Google Photos` but I don't want the `Google Photos` app to duplicate my pictures on my phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does running Google Photos in addition to the iOS Photos app cause two copies of each of my photos to be stored on my phone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326724/does-running-google-photos-in-addition-to-the-ios-photos-app-cause-two-copies-of)

Comment: @fsb the answer is wrong. I can see “Documents and Data” says 21GB in Settings. What could that be but the photos themselves?